# Java - not able to getting unique ids from HashSet

Tags: java, set, hashset

Am getting response from my API client and am setting `id` value to my bean class. After that am adding my Bean object to `HashMap` and am expecting that `CatalogSet` will remove the duplicate `id`. But its not happening. Am getting duplicate `id` after am printing it.

Please find my below code :

```
Set<Catalog> catalogSet = new HashSet<Catalog>();
Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = null;
for (SearchHit hit1 : searchHits1)
{
  sourceAsMap = hit1.getSourceAsMap();
  catalog = new Catalog();
  catalog.setId(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_id")));
  catalogSet.add(catalog);
}

for(Catalog cat:catalogSet) {
    System.out.println("Unique List --->"+cat.getId());
}
```

Please find my results that am getting which is not unique

```
Unique List --->17553
Unique List  --->546
Unique List --->40962
Unique List  --->545
Unique List  --->545
Unique List  --->901
Unique List --->17553
Unique List --->546
Unique List  --->901
Unique List  --->40962
```

Comment: Does `Catalog` override `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode`?

Comment: Yeah...you need to override `equals` so that the set will know that the same category ID means duplicate.  Currently, every entry is unique, from the point of view of having a different reference.